# SparkSQL - accesing nested structures Row( field1, field2=Row(..))

Tags: nested, apache-spark-sql

I need a help with nested structure in SparkSQL using sql method. I created a data frame on top of existing RDD (dataRDD) with a structure like this:

```
schema=StructType([ StructField("m",LongType()) ,
                  StructField("field2", StructType([
                     StructField("st",StringType()),
                     StructField("end",StringType()),
                     StructField("dr",IntegerType()) ]) )
                  ])
```

printSchema() returns this:

```
root
 |-- m: long (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- st: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dr: integer (nullable = true)
```

Creating the data frame from the data RDD and applying the schema works well.

```
df= sqlContext.createDataFrame( dataRDD, schema )
df.registerTempTable( "logs" )
```

But retrieving the data is not working:

```
res = sqlContext.sql("SELECT m, field2.st FROM logs") # <- This fails 

...org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'field.st' given input columns msisdn, field2;

res = sqlContext.sql("SELECT m, field2[0] FROM logs") # <- Also fails
...org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unresolved operator 'Project [field2#1[0] AS c0#2];

res = sqlContext.sql("SELECT m, st FROM logs") # <- Also not working
...cannot resolve 'st' given input columns m, field2;
```

So how can I access the nested structure in the SQL syntax?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You had something else happening in your testing, because `field2.st` is the correct syntax:

```
case class field2(st: String, end: String, dr: Int)

val schema = StructType(
  Array(
    StructField("m",LongType),
    StructField("field2", StructType(Array(
      StructField("st",StringType),
      StructField("end",StringType),
      StructField("dr",IntegerType) 
    )))
  )
)

val df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  sc.parallelize(Array(Row(1,field2("this","is",1234)),Row(2,field2("a","test",5678)))),
  schema
)

/* df2.printSchema
root
 |-- m: long (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- st: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dr: integer (nullable = true)
*/

val results = sqlContext.sql("select m,field2.st from df2")

/* results.show
m st
1 this
2 a
*/
```

Look back at your error message: `cannot resolve 'field.st' given input columns msisdn, field2` -- `field` vs. `field2`. Check your code again -- the names are not lining up.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. But still field2.st throws this error:
18:19:05 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, BICHDP2.TD): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.StructGetField.eval(complexTypes.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:68)
        at